# C# - TextBox TextChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm currently working on a project at work and for some reason the textchanged event of my textbox isn't firing. I've tried to put a breakpoint in my code but he doesn't get there so he the event isn't firing imo.

```
<FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSiteAlias" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBoxSiteAlias_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                                    runat="server" 
                                    id="AutoCompleteExtenderSiteAlias" 
                                    targetcontrolid="TextBoxSiteAlias"
                                    servicemethod="GetSiteAliasList"
                                    minimumprefixlength="2" 
                                    completioninterval="1000"
                                    enablecaching="true"
                                    completionsetcount="12" />
            </FooterTemplate>
```

This is my FooterTemplate in my Gridview.

```
protected void TextBoxSiteAlias_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = @"select distinct (isnull([site_address1], '')
                            +isnull([site_address2], '')
                            +isnull([site_address3], '')
                            +isnull([site_address4], '')
                            +isnull([site_address5], '') ) as 'Site_adresse' ,
                          city,
                          country,
                          [site_id] as 'siteID'
                          FROM [Henkel].[dbo].[tbl_Henkel_site_info_upload]
                          WHERE site_id = '" + ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxSiteAlias")).Text + "'";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        myTable.Load(myReader);
        conn.Close();
        if (myTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxSiteAddress")).Text = Convert.ToString(myTable.Rows[0]["Site_adresse"]);
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxSiteCity")).Text = Convert.ToString(myTable.Rows[0]["city"]);
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxSiteCountry")).Text = Convert.ToString(myTable.Rows[0]["country"]);
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxIBSSiteID")).Text = Convert.ToString(myTable.Rows[0]["siteID"]);
        }
        else
        {
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxSiteAddress")).Text = "";
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxSiteCity")).Text = "";
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxSiteCountry")).Text = "";
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxIBSSiteID")).Text = "";
        }
    }
```

This is the function that should be called as soon as the dedicated textbox looses focus.

I've been searching for a reason on many forums but all those replies indicated that the textbox needs the AutoPostBack property (which mine has).

Small notice: I have the same project (with all the same functionalities for another deal of our company and in that project it works fine. I have copied that projects code to the new project and changed all the queries + connectionstrings)

Hopefully someone can help me on this? :)

Thanks a lot

Kevin

Comment: Just saying, the way you construct your SQL Command string looks dangerous. Better use [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) to add parameters.

Comment: Maybe try making the method public. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Check if your app/page has ViewState turned on

Comment: @svinja: Making the method public didn't help.

Comment: @MichalFranc: I have tried that one too an hour ago and I've retried it just a minute ago and this didn't help neither!

Comment: *function that should be called as soon as the dedicated textbox looses focus*, won't this be called for every keypress ?

Comment: Is your page not posting back, or is the event just not firing?

Comment: @Botz3000: The good old "prone to SQL-injection" comment always gets love :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `CausesValidation` is set to false.